# Setting Headers in Response in ControllerBase vs ControllerClassHavingActualAPIs

Tags: c#, http-headers, response-headers

**I am currently working on an existing project which has below structure. In the APIs response header needs to be populated.**

**Controller folder**

|
|---> ServiceControllerBase.cs
|---> ServiceType1Controller.cs
|---> ServiceType2Controller.cs
|---> ServiceType3Controller.cs
|---> ServiceType4Controller.cs
|---> ServiceType5Controller.cs

**ServiceControllerBase.cs inherits ControllerBase**

**All other ServiceTypeXControllers.cs inherit ServiceController.cs.**

The ServiceTypeXControllers.cs are just wrappers on top of ServiceControllerBase and are there to handle the different types of authentication of each ServiceType.
As such they just use the public methods implemented in ServiceControllerBase.cs, like below.
Each ServiceTypeController has multiple methods and follow the pattern as below.

```
    public class ServiceType1Controller : ServiceControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowedAuthZPolicy(AuthorizationPolicyType.PermissionScopes)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostToSiteInclusionProtectionRules()
        {
            return await CreateInclusionRule(key, siteInclusionProtectionRule);
        }
    }
```

The ServiceControllerBase.cs does not contain APIs, but just public methods used by ServiceType Classes.

```
    public class ServiceControllerBase : ControllerBase
    {
        public async Task<ActionResult> CreateInclusionRule()
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            try
            {
                // Implementation Here
                var rule = await.Something(); 
                return Created(rule); 
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                  // Exception Handling Logic
            }
        }
    }
```

I have to add Response.Header for all the APIs. Since all the APIs are existing in ServiceTypeClasses, one option is to add the function to populate header in each API.

```
    public class ServiceType1Controller : ServiceControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowedAuthZPolicy(AuthorizationPolicyType.PermissionScopes)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostToSiteInclusionProtectionRules()
        {
            PopulateRequestIdHeader("PostToSiteInclusionProtecionRules");

            return await CreateInclusionRule(key, siteInclusionProtectionRule);
        }
    }
```

Other option is that, since all the classes are using the same BaseClass functions only, so in these functions only, the `PopulateRequestId()` function can be appended.

```
    public class ServiceControllerBase : ControllerBase
    {
        public async Task<ActionResult> CreateInclusionRule()
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            try
            {
                PopulateRequestIdHeader("CreateInclusionRule");
                // Implementation Here
                var rule = await.Something(); 
                return Created(rule); 
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                  // Exception Handling Logic
            }
        }

        protected void PopulateRequestIdHeader(string functionName)
        {
            try
            {
                // populate request-id header with guid value
                string requestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                this.Response.Headers.Add("request-id", requestId);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Exception Handling Logic
            }
        }
    }
```

I am not sure which of the above option is better?
The second option seems better since it will involve changing the functions which are being called again and again so changes will be less and can be easily validated.
But the concern I see with this approach is that the Base class does not have APIs, though it inherits from `ControllerBase`, so the `HttpContext.Response` might not make sense.

Is there any defined rule as to where the Response headers should be set, or which approach is better as per industry standards?

Answer (score 1):

You could move the codes into a filter follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#built-in-filter-attributes)

a minimal example:

Filter Attibute:

```
public class ResponseHeaderAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
        {
            string requestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("request-id", requestId);

            base.OnResultExecuting(context);
        }
    }
```

Controllers:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [ResponseHeader]
    public class ServicesTypeBaseController : ControllerBase
    { 
    }

public class ServiceType1Controller : ServicesTypeBaseController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }

 public class ServiceType2Controller : ServicesTypeBaseController
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for this approach using Attributes.

In the above case, I would like to understand which among the 2 options is better, populating using function in base class or using in actual ControllerClass

Comment: The second solution won't add  headers in the actions that not exist in your parent class.Also ,we use a filter in usual ,it's more convenient for us to decide the scope(for an action/for actions in same controller/for all actions)

Comment: All the actions of parent class are being used in the Child class. Only 5 types of actions are there and 25 APIs on top of that.

Comment: If you're sure that you won't add any action that don't exist in parent controller in feature,you could  only call the method in parent controller to reduce unnecessary codes

Comment: Okay, got it. Thank you.